# TikZ: new origin of page.center in version 3?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I updated my local TeX repository currently, and so I'm running on PGF 3.0 now. All is running great so far, but there's something strange with my own classes. Everything which uses `(current page.center)` is slighty shifted away from the original and true center of my pages.

Right now, I'm searching for a dependency to other specified lengths in the document - without success so far. Is there something official in this matter? Is page.center different now?

I really changed nothing, and page.center is used in simple and common commands - really nothing special. It's just not representing the page center as before... so confusing, no errors, warnings, nothing.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
    \node [inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {...} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Please give me hint! I couldn't find anything in the doc/changelog...

Comment: Please, show us an example with the problem.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [inner sep=0pt] (current page.center) {...}
\end{tikzpicture}`
...as I said, nothing special.

Comment: you should use `at` to place the node. `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] \node [inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {XX}; \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: I'm sorry, just forgot to type it.

Comment: @mrt, but had that solved your problem?

Comment: @Sigur: no, of course not... as I said, I didn't changed the code! it must be the new version, something is new.

Comment: @mrt, but only that piece of code is not enough since I have no problem here with it. Show us more, maybe your complete minimal preamble so we could try to reproduce the error.

Comment: BTW, [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @Sigur: impossible, it's my own class... theres nothing as normal or as similiar to classes like article. it's a complete native tex rewrite. if there's nothing known about, I need to find it out myself, but there's definitely a change in pgf code.

Comment: Could it be related? http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/295/

Comment: @Ignasi: Thanks so far, looks good... but I need to check it, please give me a second or two.

Comment: [writeLaTeX.com](http://www.writelatex.com) still uses TiKZ 2.1. I've compared a little test with `article` there and on my computer with TiKZ 3.0 and couldn't see any difference. But may be your class introduces some change.

Comment: @Ignasi: Sorry for the delay. Ignasi, it was the solution - you are brilliant. Thank you so much for the link!

Regarding your second post: Well, the reason might be my complex layout. I'm setting up everything natively instead of using geometry and others packages, and I'm using flowfram also. But it is really clean code and I don't think Till Tantau did good with changing this.

Thank you again so much, you saved me days... honestly.

Comment: @cmhughes: yes, it's an answer, and the correct one too. but i'm not a registered user, or comments can't be marked as an answer - don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been reported as [bug #295](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/295/) in [TikZ's sourceforge development place](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).

It looks to be related with some changes in file `pgfsys-pdftex.def`. I cannot provide more information because is over my skills.